# Why can't I use flask.g after a request comes?

Tags: python, flask

According to [the Flask 0.12 docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.g):

> `flask.g`
>
> ...... Starting with Flask 0.10 this is stored on the application
>   context and no longer on the request context which means it becomes
>   available if only the application context is bound **and not yet a
>   request**.

As far as I know, when a request comes, a application context will be created, if there isn't one. So shouldn't `flask.g` be available after a request has come, since the request ensures the existence of an application context?

As a bouns question: why should I store database connections on `g` instead of `request`? I know creating a application context is less "expensive" than creating a request context, but when a request comes, a request context will be created anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wording there is a little awkward. The `g` object is available during a request **as well**. A request context is nested inside an application context.

You should store a database connection in the `g` object because it'll be available *even when there is no request, such as in the [`flask shell`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/cli/#running-a-shell) command, and any [custom command-line commands](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/cli/#custom-commands). You'll need this when initialising your database, for example.

Next, there are advanced use-cases where you may want to create an 'internal' request, calling another route on your Flask app as if it came from outside. This nested request would re-use the existing app context.

There is never a request context without an application context.

Comment: Thanks sir, this makes sense. But there is a problem when a request comes and an application context already exists: from the [source code](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1949c4a9abc174bf29620f6dd8ceab9ed3ace2eb/flask/ctx.py#L230) it seems that the existing application context would be reused when  `app_ctx is None or app_ctx.app != self.app`, but the docs states that an application context [will not be shared between requests](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/appcontext/#locality-of-the-context)...

Comment: That code makes sure that the right request context is paired with the right application context, nothing more. The app context *always* already exists when a request comes in. What that code does is make sure the app context for that request is on top of the stack so that all code run for that request has the right `flask.g` object.

Comment: It only applies if more than one app context is active.

Comment: Sir, I just found out that `request` is actually accessible in the `before_request` and `after_request` hooks...

Comment: Also, I wonder in which case would one want to store something in `request`? Does doing so have _any_ advantage over storing stuff in `g`?

Comment: @SunQingyao: yes, `g` stays around if you make a subrequest. I'm currently trying to confirm if `g` is also staying around for a streaming response.

Comment: @SunQingyao: right, re-examined some of my assumptions and re-wrote the answer. The before and after hooks still have access to the request context, yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149496/discussion-between-sun-qingyao-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 2):

Answering bonus question from `Flask` [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/dbcon/):

> For instance, the `request` variable is the request object associated
>   with the current request, whereas `g` is a general purpose variable
>   associated with the current application context.

Answer (score 0):

`flask.g` is bound to the session of current request. That means that you have different `g`'s for different requests. For example, I store a user in g object for easier access to it (it's not good, but fast to access and easy to use)